# Swipe up and Swipe down in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do swipe up and swipe down like in the uploaded image using Javascript or Jquery for mobile

[image: Swipe Down]. [image]

```
$('#swipe').on('anyevent', function(e) {
   console.log(e);
   // take x,y detail from the e
   // assign height based on the x, y position
});
```

I use this code to try the swipe. But that event itself is not triggered. How to achieve this and what event I need to use for this?

Answer (score -1):

**for swipe down**

`$('#mydiv').on('swipedown',function(){alert("swipe down triggered..");} );`

**for swipe up**
`$('#mydiv').on('swipeup',function(){alert("swipe up triggered..");} );`

Click on the fiddle to see the whole code for the above two functions written.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3d9H/1/)

Comment: is this JQuery mobile?

Comment: Did you check the fiddle?

Comment: Jquery Mobile doesn't support swipeup / swipedown. Instead it support horizontal or vertical swipe .Try this plugin: https://github.com/blackdynamo/jquerymobile-swipeupdown

Comment: How to use that above plugin?

Comment: Could you please share me the jsfiddle link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216348/discussion-between-asfandyar24-and-gmv).

Comment: JavaScript does not have an `swipeup` or `swipedown` event